# Android: Pure P2P chat application

Tags: android, chat, p2p

I've started to develop a **chat application for Android**. This app is supposed to function without internet and, most importantly, without an access point; It has to connect Android devices in a **pure P2P manner**.

However I've followed the following tutorials posted in android developers guide:

- http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html
- http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html#fetch

Afterwards, I've tested my app on 3 devices, the problem is one of the devices acts as an access point, preventing other devices from connecting with each other if they are connected to it.

This doesn't work for my app, because I want each user to be able to connect to multiple users at the same time.

**What do you suggest I do in order to achieve pure P2P connection for my Android app?
Does the group owner acts as an access point?**

**EDIT**

After I've done some research I found the WiFi Direct is not suitable for my project since it has to assign a device as an access point, **what I'm looking for is WiFi ad hoc mode or (IBSS) in Android** Anybody got any suggestion on how to start working on that?

Comment: Bluetooth, maybe? If there is no internet and no wifi direct, that is my only guess.

Comment: A device can only connect to one other device. But an app on a device can connect with many apps on other devices.

Comment: But anyhow it is a wrong design to let client apps connect to each other. If a user wants to connect to other users you should do that via a server.

Comment: @greenapps You see the project's objective here is to create an app that connects people in case of a disaster where there is no Internet. Yes! what I meant was connecting multiple apps at the same time! can you please give me a hint on how to achieve that?

Comment: The hint I gave you already. So you want to connect people in a radius of ten meter about?

Comment: if you really want to do this, the best way is to **root** your device and enable ad hoc mode. This way multiple phones can communicate to each other. Other way would be attaching 3rd part devices like raspberry pi or arduino that work as a server (and your device must enable USB tethering) and communicate each other, but I don't think you'd want this.

Answer (score 0):

By using bt and wifi simultaneously, you can try to extend the network further. This will require some kind of packet routing.
Also, it seems android ignores wlan cards connected to usb otg - just plugging in extra wlan dongles could allow easy extension of network.